# MySQL: if some one trying to update column1. before update his query i want column1 value to column2 in same table

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have lead table
and column like : lead_id, **current_status**, **previous_status**

I cannot modify outsider people codes.
From outsider, people trying to update current_status column.
Before update, I want to do something **condition**, **procedure**, **trigger** or **something else** to copy the **current_status** column value to **previous_status** column only that column row which is going to update.

Thanks

Comment: Trigger is the correct way to do that.

Comment: `BEFORE UPDATE FOR EACH ROW NEW.previous_status = OLD.current_status`